# Docker image and DB Server integration

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot

We are using Docker Images for Spring Boot Rest Services. the current setup is working fine in Production. We want to use the similar setup in Development Environment. The spring boot image needs to connect to the database. At this point we have couple of options:

1. Have a centralized database server and have all the docker images from each development machine to connect to it.
2. Create a separate database image and have the developers run it along with the Spring boot image in the same Dev Machine.

Option #1 is easier to implement but if there is a change in the database, it may impact the whole development community in the organization, Option #2 mitigates that risk but it creates the problem of DataSync i.e when someone starts both these images, how to make sure it has all the required data.

I am wondering if there is any other option I need to consider or given these two options, which makes sense?

Comment: Option 1 is OKE but you have to check how many request your developers will produce and if this impacts your environment option two is also possible. For option two you can create mysql master master replication

Comment: Thanks @Noob. How do you go about creating "create mysql master master replication" in image?

Comment: I Opt for Option 2, Every developer need to be isolated when he is working on his task, untill the final output comes from him, development dependencies need to be at development machine end.  Problem with Option 1 : if some one want to update the database table column every one have to do the same when there is any change, which is not required for an individual.

Comment: Better to have the dev-properties.yml, prod-properties.yml, when you run application at dev machine use dev properties, use prop properties when you run if you are using in production.

Answer (score 0):

I went with option #2, it helps to provide isolated work environment.